# Prove $\sqrt{\frac{a}{b^2+bc+c^2}}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{c^2+ca+a^2}}+\sqrt{\frac{c}{a^2+ab+b^2}}\ge 2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\frac{(ab+bc+ca)}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}}$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, uvw

For all $a,b,c\ge 0: ab+bc+ca>0$ then prove
$$\color{black}{\sqrt{\frac{a}{b^2+bc+c^2}}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{c^2+ca+a^2}}+\sqrt{\frac{c}{a^2+ab+b^2}}\ge 2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\frac{(ab+bc+ca)}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}}.}$$
Equality holds at $a=b=c>0$ or $a=b>0; c=0$ and permutations.

Here is my proof.

We can use Holder inequality as $$\left(\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a}{b^2+bc+c^2}}\right)^2\cdot \sum_{cyc}a^2(b^2+bc+c^2)\ge (a+b+c)^3$$
and we need to prove $$(a+b+c)^3(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)\ge 8(ab+bc+ca)\sum_{cyc}a^2(b^2+bc+c^2).$$
Let $a+b+c=p=1; 0\le ab+bc+ca=q\le \frac{1}{3}; abc=r$ it becomes $$q-r\ge 8q[r+2(q^2-2r)] \iff r(24q-1)\ge q(4q-1)(4q+1) \tag{1}$$
My strategy is divide it into two cases.

*Case $1.$* $ 24q\ge 1.$

By using Schur $9r\ge 4q-1$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
r(24q-1)- q(4q-1)(4q+1)\ge \frac{4q-1}{9}(24q-1)- q(4q-1)(4q+1)=\frac{(4q-1)(1-3q)(12q-1)}{9}\ge 0,
\end{align*}
which is true when $\dfrac{1}{4}\le q\le \dfrac{1}{3}.$

And in subcase $\dfrac{1}{24}\le q <\dfrac{1}{4},$ $(1)$ is obviously true.

*Case $2.$* $ 24q\le 1.$

I use $q\ge 9r \implies r(24q-1)\ge \frac{24q^2-q}{9}.$

Thus, we obtain $$r(24q-1)- q(4q-1)(4q+1)\ge \frac{q}{9}(24q-1)- q(4q-1)(4q+1)=\frac{8q(6q+1)(1-3q)}{9}\ge 0,$$
which is true when $0\le q\le \dfrac{1}{3}.$

Hence, we solved all the cases and the proof is complete.

I'd like to ask if there is other ideas like AM-GM or Cauchy-Schwarz.

Hope you can share it to us. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Someone is trying to close this topic. Can you explain to us, why you are you doing this?

Answer (score 1):

By C-S and AM-GM we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a}{b^2+bc+c^2}}=\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a}{b^2+bc+c^2}+2\frac{\sqrt{ab(b^2+bc+c^2)(a^2+ac+c^2)}}{(b^2+bc+c^2)(a^2+ac+c^2)}\right)}=$$
$$=\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a}{b^2+bc+c^2}+\frac{2\sqrt{ab(b^2+bc+c^2)(a^2+ac+c^2)}}{(b^2+bc+c^2)(a^2+ac+c^2)}\right)}\geq$$
$$\geq\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a}{b^2+bc+c^2}+\frac{\frac{4ab}{a+b}\left(ab+\frac{c(a+b)}{2}+c^2\right)}{(b^2+bc+c^2)(a^2+ac+c^2)}\right)}$$ and it's enough to prove that:$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a}{b^2+bc+c^2}+\frac{2ab(2ab+c(a+b)+2c^2)}{(a+b)(b^2+bc+c^2)(a^2+ac+c^2)}\right)\geq\frac{8(ab+ac+bc)}{(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)},$$ which is true by $uvw$ (it's $f(w^3)\geq0,$ where $f$ is a concave function).

Can you end it now?